# SharePoint 2013 Power shell Search query and document download

Tags: 2013

Good Afternoon All,

My google skills are completely letting me down at the moment. 
Our SharePoint Admin is currently on leave and i have been tasked to do a search in our SharePoint environment.

I need to complete a search via powershell to query all documents and that must contain some sentences and other key works (some queries are up to 4 search criteria) and i also need to download a copy of all the files found.

Query 1 for example would be download all documents that contain the Sentence = "the red house is blue" and contains the word "black"

Any advise would be fantastic

Answer (score 1):

Before getting started, we need to make sure we load the Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query Assembly within our PowerShell session. Our code will by using objects from that namespace.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query”)
```

My code uses the Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery object to retrieve search results back. This object takes in a reference to a Site Collection to perform the search against.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://localhost

$keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($site)
```

Next step is to prompt the user to input a keyword for the search results. Once obtained, we will assign this keyword to QueryText property our newly created KeywordQuery object.

```
$keyword = Read-Host “Search Term”

$keywordQuery.QueryText = $keyword
```

We now have an object that represent our query to send to the server, but in order to execute this Query, we need to instantiate a second object, the `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor`. This object exposes a method name ExecuteQuery() to which we wil pass our query object in order to get search results back.

```
$searchExec = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor

$searchResults = $searchExec.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)
```

The last step for us is to look at the Table property of the returned object in order to get a list of items that have been identified as matching our search criterias. For clarity’s sake, we will only be exposing the Title, Path, Author, LastModifiedTime and IsDocument property of each search result.

```
$table = $searchResults.Table

$table | Select Title, Path, Author, LastModifiedTime, IsDocument
```

Now, let us put our PowerShell script together:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query”)
Write-Host “`r`n”

$site = Get-SPSite http://localhost
$keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($site)
$keyword = Read-Host “Search Term”
$keywordQuery.QueryText = $keyword
$searchExec = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor
$searchResults = $searchExec.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)

Write-Host “`r`n”
$table = $searchResults.Table
Write-Host $table.Length” Results Found” -BackgroundColor “Green” -ForegroundColor “Black”
$table | select Title, Path, Author, LastModifiedTime, IsDocument
```

[SOURCE](https://nikcharlebois.com/get-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell/)

The above approach will get the result details, but doesn't download, you can use that manually.

Also refer the below links for more approaches,

1. https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/powershell-to-search-sharepoint-export-results-using-keyword-query.html
2. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Query-SharePoint-2013-373ff97a

Comment: I have looked at all your suggestions. But i have not been able to get "contains "the red house is blue" AND/OR  "Black"

All the information i have been able to find does not search the contents of the documents, Only the metadata of the document